# Get a name of a method parameter using Javassist

Tags: javassist

I have a `CtMethod` instance, but I don't know how to get names of parameters (not types) from it. I tried `getParameterTypes`, but it seems it returns only types.

I'm assuming it's possible, because libraries I'm using don't have sources, just class files and I can see names of method parameters in IDE.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is indeed possible to retrieve arguments' names, but only if the code has been compiled with debug symbols otherwise you won't be able to do it.

To retrieve this information you have to access the method's local variable table. For further information about this data structure I suggest you to check section [4.7.13. The LocalVariableTable Attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.13) of the [jvm spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html). As I usually say, JVM spec may look bulky but it's an invaluable friend when you're working at this level!

### Accessing the local variable table attribute of your ctmethod

```
  CtMethod method = .....;
  MethodInfo methodInfo = method.getMethodInfo();
  LocalVariableAttribute table = methodInfo.getCodeAttribute().getAttribute(javassist.bytecode.LocalVariableAttribute.tag);
```

You now have the the local variable attribute selected in `table` variable.

### Detecting the number of localVariables

```
   int numberOfLocalVariables = table.tableLenght();
```

Now keep in mind two things regarding the number in `numberOfLocalVariables`:

- **1st**: local variables defined inside your method's body will also be accounted in tableLength();
- **2nd**: if you're in a non static method so will be `this` variable.

The order of your local variable table will be something like:

`|this (if non static) | arg1 | arg2 | ... | argN | var1 | ... | varN|`

### Retriving the argument name

Now if you want to retrieve, for example, the arg2's name from the previous example, it's the 3rd position in the array. Hence you do the following:

```
 // remember it's an array so it starts in 0, meaning if you want position 3 => use index 2
 int frameWithNameAtConstantPool = table.nameIndex(2); 
 String variableName = methodInfo.getConstPool().getUtf8Info(frameAtConstantPool)
```

You now have your variable's name in `variableName`.

**Side Note**: I've taken you through the *scenic route* so you could learn a bit more about Java (and javassists) internals. But there are already tools that do this kind of operations for you, I can remember at least one by name called [paranamer](https://github.com/paul-hammant/paranamer). You might want to give a look at that too.

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thank you for explaining :), I'll try to implement it via Javassist using your code snippets (even though it might a bit harder than using the paranamer). Also I found some code which might be doing the parameter searching as well (haven't tried it, but it could be useful for other readers) - http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.slf4j/slf4j-ext/1.6.1/org/slf4j/instrumentation/JavassistHelper.java.

Comment: it does work with Javaassist 3.18.2 (and later, at least up to 3.19 anyway) if you cast, like so:          LocalVariableAttribute nameTable = (LocalVariableAttribute) methodInfo.getCodeAttribute().getAttribute(LocalVariableAttribute.tag);

Comment: Is it possible also to *set* the variable names, using a similar inverse procedure?

Comment: @Panayotis: Never tried it, but conceptually is possible. You first would add new names to the constant pool using `addUtf8Info` method. This method returns an integer that represents the frame's index. You would then need to replace the LocalVariableAttribute (this would be the trickiest part) by a new one where you would add the new entries using `addEntry` method and finally write the class.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't actually want the names of the parameters, but just want to be able to access them, you can use "$1, $2, ..." as seen [in this tutorial](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html).

Comment: The link is dead, here's an updated one: http://www.javassist.org/tutorial/tutorial2.html

Answer (score 0):

It works with Javaassist 3.18.2 (and later, at least up to 3.19 anyway) if you cast, like so:

```
LocalVariableAttribute nameTable = (LocalVariableAttribute)methodInfo.getCodeAttribute().getAttribute(LocalVariableAttribute.tag);
```